# Memory Management of Very Large 3D Array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, 64-bit

I need to make a very large 3D array. By large, I mean 6000x1000x1000. Each element is to hold  a struct that contains 3 doubles. This array is to represent a physical vector field and each array element is to contain the vector values.

I need to declare the array dynamically and have read two ways of doing this: using the vector class or using pointers. Both examples are shown below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct myVector {
    double Bx;
    double By;
    double Bz;
};

#define HEIGHT 10
#define WIDTH 10
#define DEPTH 50
//these are your sizes

void fill(myVector ***p3DArray);
void print(myVector ***const p3DArray);

int main() {
   myVector ***p3DArray; //any name you want

  // Allocate memory
  // Replace "Struct" with the name of your struct
  p3DArray = new myVector**[HEIGHT];
  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    p3DArray[i] = new myVector*[WIDTH];

    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
      p3DArray[i][j] = new myVector[DEPTH];
  }

  // Assign values
  p3DArray[0][0][0].Bx = 3.6;
  p3DArray[1][2][4].Bz = 4.0;

  fill(p3DArray);
  //print(p3DArray);

  // De-Allocate memory to prevent memory leak
  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
      delete [] p3DArray[i][j];

    delete [] p3DArray[i];
  }
  delete [] p3DArray;

  return 0;
}
```

And

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct myVector {
    double Bx;
    double By;
    double Bz;
};

#define HEIGHT 1000
#define WIDTH 1000
#define DEPTH 500

void fill(vector<vector<vector<myVector>>> &Array);
void print(vector<vector<vector<myVector>>> &Array);

int main() {
  vector<vector<vector<myVector> > > array3D;

  // Set up sizes. (HEIGHT x WIDTH)
  array3D.resize(HEIGHT);
  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    array3D[i].resize(WIDTH);

    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
      array3D[i][j].resize(DEPTH);
  }

  // Put some values in
  array3D[1][2][5].Bx = 6.0;
  array3D[3][1][4].By = 5.5;

  fill(array3D);

  return 0;
}
```

For the size 1000x1000x500, my computer runs out of memory and freezes. I need to go bigger than this. Using sizeof(), I found that a single element takes up 24 bytes. For 1000x1000x500 elements, that is 12 Gb. I'm using Microsoft Visual c++ 2010, the 64-bit debugger and operating system, and have 8 Gb of RAM.

Do I simply not have enough RAM, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you split your problem into smaller cube of elements ?

Comment: First of all, if you're going to use old-fashioned arrays like that, keep them in an std::unique_ptr so you don't forget to delete them. You do not want to cram that amount of data in memory at the same time... Typical alternative approaches would be streaming (i.e. processing small parts of your data at a time) or if that doesn't work, storing the data in a database or simply in blocks on disk that can be fetched into memory as needed.

Comment: Wow… now that is a big array… probably need more ram even if you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

To reach your goal of 6000x1000x1000, you are not going to be able to store all of that data in RAM at once.  For that many elements, at 24-bytes per element, you are talking approximately 134 GB of data.

What you will probably want to do is to design your own class that retrieves elements from disk instead of allocating everything in a single contiguous block of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class (let's call it "3dArray") which hides the storage implementation from a client. In that class, you **should not store the entire contents** of the 3D array. Store *only* values which are explictly written. In your example, you are only setting two data points, so why not store only these two data points (in whatever way)? In order to do so, get away from the idea of needing a vector or array with HEIGHT x WIDTH x DEPTH elements. Instead, use something like:

```
std::map<Coord, myVector> written_points;

...

void 3dArray::SetPoint(int x, int y, int z, myVector const &value)
{
    written_points[Coord(x, y, z)] = value; 
}
```

Furthermore, when returning results of operations, return proxy objects which defer real computation.

For example, let's say your class should support multiplication:

```
3dArray a1;
3dArray a2;
3dArray a3 = multiply(a1, a2);
std::cout << a3.GetPoint(10, 20, 30);
```

The result of the multiplication is almost entirely thrown away here - only *one* data point of the entire huge result is needed. Why multiply the whole thing? If this idea looks interesting to you, have a look at Item 17 in Scott Meyers' *More Effective C++* book: "Consider using lazy evaluation".

Finally, remember that the effectiveness of any such optimisation technique depends on how the data is used in your application.

Comment: The code was primarily taken online from C++.com. In actuality, I will be using all of the points, not two of them. So, I will indeed write all of the values. First, I create the array, then fill it full of values (hence the arbitrary fill function). I will then use those values in my analysis of the vector field. If I understand, that still mitigates making my own class, correct?

Comment: Well, if you really need *all* elements all the time, then in fact it would be pointless to use lazy evaluation, and you'd have to resort to disk storage. However, consider this: what if 99% (or 90%, or maybe even 50%) of the points are 0? In that case, it still makes a lot of sense to store only the coordinates and values of the few points that are *not* 0, doesn't it? So it not only depends on the operations you perform but also on the kind of data you wish to represent. In any case, yes, making your own class is a good idea here.